# Linqpad not showing stored procedures with non-dbo schema

Tags: sql-server, linqpad

I've been using LinqPad for a while now, but have only noticed this problem recently. We have some stored procedures in our DB that have a schema other than dbo, such as `[admin].[ClearTransientData]`.

When I connect to that database with LinqPad, it will only show the stored procedures with the `[dbo]` schema.

The schema in question is owned by the dbo role and I'm connecting to the database with an account in the dbo role. When I connect to the same database with SSMS using the same account, I can see all of the sprocs no matter the schema.

Am I missing something in the connection definition?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer, thanks to a prompting from the mobile stackexchange app. I cannot find the user that contacted me (if it was you, please add a comment to the question above or post an answer so I can mark it correct).

Anyway, the default grouping in Linqpad is:

- Schema

  - Tables (only nested in the default schema)
  - Functions
  - Stored Procs
  - Views

However, for the default schema (dbo in this case), that grouping is left out, so 'Tables', 'Functions', 'Stored Procs' and 'Views' appear at the top level. This led me to believe that *all* stored procedures would be grouped at the top 'Stored Procs' level, then sub-grouped by shcema name under that. This is not the case.

All I had to do was expand the 'Admin' schema[1] in the tree and there was the 'Stored Procs' grouping I was looking for.

- Admin

  - Table1
  - Table2
- Stored Procs

  - proc1
  - proc2

Thanks,
Mark

[1] the name of the schema in question actually begins with 'V', which placed deep in the tree view. Since I'm lazy and had to scroll down to see it, I didn't see it right away.

Comment: It appears I was just as lazy as you. Thanks for sharing!

Comment: Perfect, just what I needed :)